# MongoDB/Mongoose: Sorting within a populated field

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am pretty new to MongoDB and i am unable to find a solution to the following:

I am trying to sort personnel after their ranks.

```
CollectionPerson: _id, name, {rank_id}

CollectionRank: _id, RankName, level
```

What I am trying to accomplish ist to get a list in order of the rank level.

Any solution or direction pointing would be nice.

/edit:

MyModels:

```
const RankSchema = new Schema({
    level: Number,
    dgGrp: Number,
    dgSold: String,
    dgNATO: String,
    hut: {
        bezX: String,
        bezM: String,
        bezS: String,
        img: String
    },
    lut: {
        bezX: String,
        bezM: String,
        bezS: String,
        img: String
    },
    mut: {
        bezX: String,
        bezM: String,
        bezS: String,
        img: String
    }
});

const PersonalSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    vname: String,
    pNum: {
        type: String,
        default: '01010101',
    },
    pKenn: {
        type: String,
        default: '010101-A-01010',
    },
    dg: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Rank'
    },
    uni: String,
    sex: String,
    konf: String,
    adresse: {
        str: String,
        plz: Number,
        ort: String,
        land: String,
        staat: String
    }
});
```

My Query:

```
const personal = await Personal.find({}).populate({ path: 'dg', options: { sort: { level: 1 } } });
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what have you already tried

Comment: Hi Abbas, thank you for your reply. I editet the initial post, to hopefully clear things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Population is done on client side by Mongoose after the query fetching the base documents has already executed. As such, sorting the base documents has already been done (if requested).

You can:

- Construct an aggregation pipeline, $lookup and $sort yourself.
- Let Mongoose populate your documents then reorder them as you wish in your application.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. How would I implement the aggregation in nodejs? I figured out htte following DB String: 
db.getCollection('personals').aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "ranks", localField: "dg", foreignField: "_id", as: "rank"}},{$unwind: "$rank"},{$sort:{"rank.dgGrp":-1 ,"rank.level":-1}}])

Comment: Feel free to ask that as a new question.